# React hook, accessing state value directly after updating it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this has been asked a lot and in many different ways but I couldn't find something that works for me. The functionality I want in my code is this

```
const TestApp() => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(null);
  const updateAndShowCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    // This console.log should be happen after setCount() has completed it's job
    console.log(count);
  }
}
```

The function will be called by a button onClick effect. What it currently does is to update `count` and print the value of `count` before the update.

**I want the button press to update `count` and immediately "after" print the updated value.**

This is a test case for achieving what I want, in my actual project the function will receive a value from an input field and then make a get request using that value (with axios).
I am assuming that the answer to this simple test case will work in my case as well, and since this asynchronous behaviour is something I don't quite understand yet I thought it would be sensible to get a grasp of the general concept first.

From what I have gathered though, I think I should mention that `useEffect()` is already being used for an initial get request, so if your answer involves using that you should assume that I don't know how to add something to `useEffect()` while retaining it's current functionality.

The current `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("mybackend/").then(res) => {
    setRequestData(res.data);
  });
}, []);
```

My actual question is in bold for clarity. Any info regarding the situation as a whole is welcome as well. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Because javascript *passes by value*, it's literally impossible to do what you want. The problem why there are so many questions about this topic is because this is not a react thing and it's also completely irrelevant whether `setCount` is async or not. It's simply not possible. If you want the new value immediately, use what you pass to `setCount` (`count + 1`).

Answer (score 1):

The solution follows naturally when adding `count` to your request (I guess it's some query parameter of some sort), because as you then use `count` inside the effect, it is a *dependency* of the effect, thus whenever the dependency changes, the effect will run again:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("mybackend?count=" + count).then(res) => {
   setRequestData(res.data);
  });
}, [count]);
```

Note that the effect is still missing a *cleanup* callback, which would cancel an ongoing request, so that when `count` changes again while the request is still ongoing, not two requests run at the same time concurrently.

Comment: This works perfectly in my case. If you could also advise me on how to implement a "loading" prop while the request is being processed so that the `count` variable can't be modified until then it would be the optimal. Regardless of that, your answer is awesome, thanks for your time :)

Comment: `if(requestData === null) /* don't do something */`

Answer (score 0):

i'am not sure that i understood your question completely, but i think the answer is: you should use the callback in your setState, like that:

```
setCount(count => count + 1)
```